# What causes a box with square dots to appear around my active links?

Tags: css

When I hover over and them move away from active links on my web page I see a box appear around the link. The edge of the box is a series of dots.

I have been trying to see what causes this with Chrome Developer tools but I cannot seem to catch it.

Can someone tell me what is causing this and what CSS can I use to stop it appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend adding this to the active and focus of your a tag.

```
a:active, a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're referring to is caused by `outline`, you can simply use something like

```
outline:none;
```

you might be able to replicate this behavior here http://jsfiddle.net/9x46cyfd/

Answer (score 1):

Change focused style for links by adding

```
   a:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
```